# I want to rename my single url to subdomain url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rename

I want rename my URL: `https://www.example.com/onlysinglepage` URL to `https://sub.example.com/onlysinglepage`

In this rename URL content comes from the maindomain just display on the subdomain. Nothing on the subdomain.

This is possible via .htaccess file?

Comment: Are you created subdomain?

Comment: Yes, I have created subdomain.

Comment: "Nothing on the subdomain." - It would be far simpler to point the subdomain to the same directory as the main domain's document root at the time you create the subdomain. Otherwise you need to include directives on the subdomain and enable mod_proxy (as a reverse proxy) to proxy requests to the main domain.